# How long (time slots) does a functional unit take to fetch an operand?

Tags: dependencies, cpu-architecture

In computer architecture, functional units take up time slots to execute instructions.

For functional units that take more than 1 time slots to execute, do they need to be reading from the registers for the entire span of execution or do they only need to read them during the first time slot?

For example, if we have something like

```
3 <- F(1,2),
```

where 1,2, and 3 denote registers and F is a functional unit that takes 2 time slots to execute.

Would F1 be occupying the registers 1 and 2 for read during all 2 time slots, or would it only be occupying it for the first time slot? This is important due to possible WAR dependency issues in instructions that follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is dependent on how you implement it; both types are possible. But the common way is reading once.

It is highly likely for the functional unit to latch input values in the first cycle. Note 1: a functional unit might require the operands for only one cycle even if the operation takes more. This is also dependent on functional unit type and its implementation. Even if the functional unit needs the original operands for more than one cycle, it can latch operands. Note 2: In current processors, functional units read their operands only one time (they could read from register file or other units), but an out-of-order processor might move the same operands multiple times between different units.

Note 3: the notion of a functional unit "occupying the registers" is not technically correct. A functional unit can read or write registers, but cannot occupy registers (an instruction can occupy a functional unit or reservation station, but this is beyond the scope of this question).